# Looking for a .NET binary tree

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a well tested simple in-memory binary tree implementation for c#. I would appreciate any pointers...

Comment: no - I needed it for a project i'm working on.

Comment: How in the world is this "off topic"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .NET framework already contains them, they are just not advertised as such.  Probably because of the inherent ambiguity in the three different ways to iterate a tree.  SortedDictionary uses a self-balancing red-black tree under the hood and has the same time and space complexity as a binary tree.  You'll need SortedList if your tree contains duplicates.

Comment: Excellent just what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364091%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) article on MSDN? (An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0 ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very well tested one: [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BinarySearchTree.aspx) found at CodeProject. Has worked for me.