# C# storing linked list in binary trees nodes

Tags: c#, linked-list, binary-tree

i would like to develop a binary tree structure such that every single node stores a key and a linked list. the reason behind such implementation is that i would like to do a search within the binary tree (Binary search tree) with appropriate key and the linked list will serve as storing structure that i could easily retrieve any information at anytime. Can anyone help me on this approach? or if anyone can suggest a better approach would be appreciated.

P.S: Using binary tree is due to performance of searching algorithm O(log n) and the use of linked list is due that the structure has to be dynamic so i cant use arrays since its structure is static.

Comment: The simplest method is to use built-in classes, like `SortedDictionary<Key, List<Item>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Sorted Diccionary: "The SortedDictionary(Of TKey, TValue) generic class is a binary search tree with O(log n) retrieval", check the documentation :[SortedDiccionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using one of the built-in ones, such as the SortedDictionary described in this other stack post:  [Looking for a .NET binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613924/looking-for-a-net-binary-tree)

Answer (score 0):

[NGenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/) project is a awesome collection of data structures and algorithms including a [Binary Tree](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/wiki/BinaryTree). Use it with [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class like:

```
BinaryTree<LinkedList<T>> tree;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use implementations provided in other answers. If you want to understand how to write this yourself, here is  a sample that I adopted from my Huffman coding project. It's not perfect but you can see a general idea.

**I will start from usage**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] testData = new string[] { "aa", "bbb", "cccccc", "d", "ee", "ffffff", "ggggg" };
        var expected = new BinaryNode<string>("ffffff");
        IBinaryTree<string> tree = new BinaryTree<string>();
        tree.Build(testData);

        var result = tree.Root.Traverse(expected, new List<IBinaryNode<string>>());
    }
}
```

**Binary node interface and implementation**

```
public interface IBinaryNode<T>
{
    int? ID { get; }
    T Data { get; set; }
    IBinaryNode<T> RightChild { get; set; }
    IBinaryNode<T> LeftChild { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> Traverse(IBinaryNode<T> current, IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> recursionData);
}

public class BinaryNode<T> : IBinaryNode<T>
{
    public int? ID{get; private set;}
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public IBinaryNode<T> RightChild { get; set; }
    public IBinaryNode<T> LeftChild { get; set; }

    public BinaryNode():this(default(T)){}
    public BinaryNode(T data):this(data, null){}
    public BinaryNode(T data, int? id)
    {
        Data = data;
        ID = id;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> Traverse(IBinaryNode<T> current, IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> recursionData)
    {
        // no children found
        if (RightChild == null && LeftChild == null)
        {
            //correct guess BinaryNode has the needed data
            if (current.Data.Equals(Data))
            {
                return recursionData;
            }

            //wrong value - try another leg
            return null;
        }

        //there are children
        IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> left = null; //tmp left storage
        IEnumerable<IBinaryNode<T>> right = null; //tmp right storage

        //start with the left child
        //and travers in depth by left leg
        if (LeftChild != null)
        {
            //go in depth through the left child 
            var leftPath = new List<IBinaryNode<T>>();

            //add previously gathered recursionData
            leftPath.AddRange(recursionData);

            leftPath.Add(LeftChild);

            //recursion call by rigth leg
            left = LeftChild.Traverse(current, leftPath);
        }

        //no left children found
        //travers by right leg in depth now
        if (RightChild != null)
        {
            //go in depth through the right child 
            var rightPath = new List<IBinaryNode<T>>();

            //add previously gathered recursionData
            rightPath.AddRange(recursionData);

            //add current value 
            rightPath.Add(RightChild);

            //recursion call by rigth leg
            right = RightChild.Traverse(current, rightPath);
        }

        //return collected value of left or right
        if (left != null)
        {
            return left;
        }

        return right;
    }
}
```

**Binary tree interface and implementation**

```
public interface IBinaryTree<T>
{
    void Build(IEnumerable<T> source);
    IBinaryNode<T> Root { get; set; }
}

public class BinaryTree<T> : IBinaryTree<T>
{
    private readonly List<IBinaryNode<T>> nodes;
    private int nodeId = 0;

    public IBinaryNode<T> Root { get; set; }

    public BinaryTree()
    {
        nodes = new List<IBinaryNode<T>>();
    }

    public bool IsLeaf(IBinaryNode<T> binaryNode)
    {
        return (binaryNode.LeftChild == null && binaryNode.RightChild == null);
    }

    public void Build(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var node = new BinaryNode<T>(item, nodeId);
            nodeId++;
            nodes.Add(node);
        }

        //construct a tree
        while (nodes.Count > 1) //while more than one node in a list
        {
            var taken = nodes.Take(2).ToList();

            // Create a parent BinaryNode and sum probabilities
            var parent = new BinaryNode<T>()
            {
                LeftChild = taken[0],
                RightChild = taken[1]
            };

            //this has been added so remove from the topmost list
            nodes.Remove(taken[0]);
            nodes.Remove(taken[1]);
            nodes.Add(parent);
        }

        Root = nodes.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```